# How NetSuite RESTlet(ss2.1) get The remote client IP address

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, restlet, suitescript2.0, netsuite-rest-api

In NetSuite RESTlet Scripts(SS2.1),
You can only get the request body, nothing else.
So, Any else method That we can get The remote client IP address?